# Entity-Tracking Distance for Mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with Increasing the Minimum Entity-Tracking Distance, again, for my Custom Map - as I have run into a problem...

The problem mentioned above, is that when the Mobs are spawned by my command blocks, they aren't actually proceeding towards their Main Objective, instead lazing around doing nothing... :|

Can the ETD be increased through commands? Or do I have to move the Main Objective (for the Mobs) closer to their Spawn Locations for them to get interested? I am really not sure about this.

If you have an answer, feel free to contribute, I'd love to hear. I'm all ears. :)

Comment: fyi you don't need to mark a question as [answered] in the title, accepting the answer is enough to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this being configurable, you need something more than Vanilla server, you need Spigot. It has this configuration in it's basic settings, however that might not be usable for your map at all. And it only sets the default distances to all mobs.

You can however **spawn your own entities with custom [attributes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute)**, namely `generic.followRange` one, that can modify the tracking distance of a mob:

> The range in blocks within which a mob with this attribute will target players or other mobs to track. Exiting this range will cause the mob to cease following the player/mob. Actual value used by most mobs is 16; for zombies it is 40.
>
> Minimum is 0, maximum 2048

Be aware that this method **won't work** for **self-spawned mobs**, that ones would need some plugin to change them, or beforementioned Spigot server. You need to spawn all mobs yourself, via command blocks or spawners. And one note more - if mobs go outside of active radius around player, they need to be persistent (so they don't despawn) and they need to be in loaded chunk, to be able to move.

Example of attribute-changed mob to spawn: (you can construct your own for example [here](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/))

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.followRange,Base:80}]}
```

**Be also aware that high values of this parameter for a lot of mobs might be really high performance hit for user!**

Comment: @Antoine_Hejilk Thank you! This definitely did the trick, as when spawning mobs, they Actually Proceed Towards the Players!